# How to set a a variable with Jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

I have two variables like this:

```
var th = $(".on", parent.document.body).find('input').eq(0).val();
var th2 = $(".on", parent.document.body).find('input').eq(1).val();
```

Now I want to do an `if` statement including the two vars:

```
if ($(th + th2, parent.document.body).val() == ''){ 

...


}
```

This doesn't work for me. I can't figure out why. I also tried other variations with no luck.

Comment: Could you provide some sample values returned by the `th` and `th2` variables which would make your question more clear? Are you trying to test if the 2 inputs are empty?

Comment: Hi, they are not suppose to return anything, if `val()==''` then do something

Comment: So you are trying to test if the 2 input fields are empty and do not contain values and if so perform some action?

Comment: don't repeat yourself - cache `var $in = $(parent.document.body).find('.on input'); var th = $in[0].value; var th2 = $in[1].value`

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov Yes, exactly

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you very much, very enlightening(:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to test whether the 2 input fields are empty you could test against their values you have stored in your variables:

```
if (th == '' && th2 == '') {
    // the 2 input fields are empty    
}
```

Comment: @thebjorn, the `.val()` method already returns a string, so you could also use the `===` if you want.

Answer (score 3):

As jQuery is a JavaScript framework, you can use plain JavaScript

```
if(th == '' && th2 == '') { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you've extracted the two field values, you're just doing string comparisons, so use normal Javascript.

However you *probably* also want to ignore any white space that the user may have left in the fields, so I would use:

```
if ($.trim(th) === '' && $.trim(th2) === '') {
     // both fields are "empty"
     ...
}
```

You should also avoid code repetition, and take advantage of native Javascript and DOM calls when you can:

```
var $in = $(parent.document.body).find('.on input');  // Don't repeat yourself
var th = $in[0].value;   // more efficient than $in.eq(0).val()
var th2 = $in[1].value
```